# Out Of Memory error while parsing SOAP response

Tags: soap

I am getting a large SOAP response with around 10000+ rows of data and am extracting the relevant data from within CDATA and inserting into a Database.

The code looks as :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setCoalescing(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(resp.getBytes());
Document doc = db.parse(is);
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(fetchResult);
String result = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

resp contains the SOAP response
fetchResult is

```
String fetchResult = "//result/text()";
```

I'm getting OutofMemory error in the last line. I did try with incresing heap size to 1.2 GB , but that also didn't work.

Could any of you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Process the document as a stream, rather than consuming the entire response as a `Document`.  The code you have at the moment builds the structure representing the document in memory, and then attempts to evaluate an XPath expression upon it.

A more memory efficient approach would be to use a [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) parser instead (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html)).  By using a SAX parser, you'll stream the through the document as needed keeping only a tiny part of the document in memory at any one time.

Comment: thanks Jeff for the solution. However I'm not able to come up with the code. Could you please help me out?